# How to fix ClassNotFoundException org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 even though the dependency was added?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt password from a file on IntelliJ while working on Scala Sbt project. This is my scala class:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.util

import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

class DataEncrypt {

    def encrypt(key: String, value: String): String = {
        val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyToSpec(key))
        Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8")))
    }

    def decrypt(key: String, encryptedValue: String): String = {
        val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyToSpec(key))
        new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedValue)))
    }

    def keyToSpec(key: String): SecretKeySpec = {
        var keyBytes: Array[Byte] = (SALT + key).getBytes("UTF-8")
        val sha: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
        keyBytes = sha.digest(keyBytes)
        keyBytes = util.Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, 16)
        new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES")
    }

    private val SALT: String = "jMhKlOuJnM34G6NHkqo9V010GhLAqOpF0BePojHgh1HgNg8^72k"

}
```

My build.sbt file:

```
name := "AnalyzeTables"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec
libraryDependencies += "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.13"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.8.1"
```

I am creating a jar file from the project and executing it on cli by running the command:

```
scala -cp /home/user/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar analyzetables_2.11-0.1.jar tablename
```

where analyzetables_2.11-0.1.jar is my jar file and tablename is my argument which I am reading in the code. If I submit the code, I see class not found exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.enc.DataEncrypt.decrypt(DataEncrypt.scala:21)
    at com.db.manager.GpConnection.<init>(GpConnection.scala:13)
    at com.gp.analyze.GetStats.run_analyze(GetStats.scala:21)
```

Which exactly occurs at: `new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedValue)))` I tried to find solutions online for the issue I faced and most of the answers were adding the jar file: `commons-codec` to the project which I already have in the build.sbt file. I have the import statement and also tried to see if this works:

```
new String(cipher.doFinal(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedValue)))
```

But all of them are giving `classNotFoundException`. I also tried to create a fat jar by doing:

```
project Structure->Artifacts-> + ->jars->from modules with dependencies and run the fat jar.
```

In this case, I see NullPointerException.

My project Structure:
[image]

Could anyone let me know if I have to do a setting change or add any missing jar file ?

Comment: You have to put it on your classpath, either by making a fat jar or adding it to -cp a.jar:b.jar, or -cp a.jar;b.jar on one unfortunate OS.

Comment: Sample `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.8")`

Comment: I put this addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.8") in build.sbt file ? I don't have assembly.sbt file.

Comment: What @som-snytt mentioned is sbt plugin `sbt-assembly`  - https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly - it allows to build fat jar, which will put all your dependencies in a one jar. Please, take a look at project GitHub for more details.